# Mwe2 Workflow - modify variables at runtime

Tags: eclipse, workflow, generator, mwe

I'm trying to make a tool in which the users can choose a model for the mwe2 file and then the generated file to be placed where the user wanted (directory etc..) 
My question is if the following can be done:

1. to dynamically change the model path and the output outlet path (at
   runtime)
2. to run the mwe2 file at runtime (to don't need to go to press right
   click and run as ..stuff)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that this cannot be done, but is another way to achieve the same result.
Found the solution here: [create context-menu generator](http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/)